# About form submit with javascript

Tags: php

If I submit forms without input(type="submit") and I use a href with javascript, like this:

```
<a href="javascript:document.form-name.submit();" rel="nofollow">Button</a>
```

Is a way to check with php what form is submitted? (with input, I use `if (isset($_POST['input-name']))`)

Comment: Fixed your references to Java. `Java is to JavaScript like Car is to Carpet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include a hidden field in your form that contains the form identification data you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this temporarily to understand what PHP is receiving from the POST array.

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Natively? Not through JS. You'll need to modify the values which are sent. There are a couple of ways to do that:

- Change the action: `<form action="/processor.php?input-name=INPUT!">` Then get the value from $_GET in PHP (warning, this will not work if the request is a get request).
- Add a hidden input: `<input type="hidden" name="input-name" value="INPUT!" />` The value will now be part of either $_GET or $_POST, depending on the action of the form.